# Adding eclipse UI form to a AbstractDecoratedTextEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add a form in the lower half of text area in AbstractDecoratedTextEditor but the form shows up in the right half of the editor by default. Is there a way to have the form displayed in the lower half of the editor without writing a text editor from scratch and adding the text area and form in a grid layout ? This is the class I have so far.

```
public class Editor extends AbstractDecoratedTextEditor
{
  public Editor()
  {
    super();
    setDocumentProvider(new DocumentProvider());
  }

  @Override
  public void init(final IEditorSite site, final IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException
  {
    super.init(site, input);
    if (input instanceof EditorInput)
    {
       text = ((EditorInput) input).getText();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
  {
    super.createPartControl(parent);

    final FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
    final Form form = toolkit.createForm(parent);
    form.setText("Testing.... 1 2 3.....");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply set layout of parent (composite).. you can set any layout.
e.g you can use 
FillLayout filllayout = new FillLayout();
        filllayout.type = SWT.VERTICAL;
        filllayout.spacing =5;
        filllayout.marginHeight=5;
        filllayout.marginWidth=5;
        parent.setLayout(filllayout);
super.createPartControl(parent); 
Hope, this will work.